# Orthogonal unit vectors

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and consider the orthogonal projection $\pi$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto W. Let $(a_i,b_i)^t$ be the coordinate vector of $\pi(e_i)$, with respect to a chosen orthonormal basis of $W$. Prove that $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ are orthogonal unit vectors.

Comment: Why did 2 people ask to close it because it's not related to math ?

Comment: They voted to close it because people get touchy when you merely state a question and don't say what you tried (because they, understandably, dislike it when people use this site as a machine for churning out their homework, rather than one for learning). Saying what you tried is useful though - it help people know where you problems lie so they can focus their help better.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Orthogonal maps map orthogonal vectors to orthogonal vectors.

**Proof:** Suppose $\;u\perp v\iff u\cdot v=0\;$ and let $\;P\;$ be an orthogonal map, then

$$Px\cdot Py=x\cdot P^*Py=x\cdot y=0$$

Comment: Could you give me some more detail ?

Comment: What is *your* definition of "orthogonal map", @Carpediem ? There are several equivalent ones, say $$Px\cdot Py=x\cdot y\;,\;\;P^*P=PP^*=I\iff P^*=P^{-1}\;,\;\;etc.$$and thus we get what I wrote...

Comment: Well $p$ is an orthogonal projection if and only if $$\forall (x,y) \in E^2, \langle p(x),y \rangle =\langle x, p(y) \rangle$$

Comment: I assume the question means that $\pi$ just projects by dropping a perpendicular down onto $W$. That's not an "orthogonal map" as defined by DonAntonio. But it can be used to construct one...

Comment: I think apt1002 may be on to something and I may have mistranslated something here...I shall check and edit my answer accordingly later.

Comment: @DonAntonio Have you seen my comment regarding the projection ?

Comment: Yes I have, @Carpediem. I shall mull a little while on this now.

Answer (score 0):

We let $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$.  Let $w_1,w_2$ be the orthonormal basis of $W$ that the projections are taken with respect to above.  Let $w_1=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and $w_2=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$.  Let $\pi$ be the projection mapping; this is a linear transformation.  Then

$\pi(w_1)=x_1(a_1w_1+b_1w_2)+ x_2(a_2w_1+b_2w_2)+x_3(a_3w_1+b_3w_3) 
=\langle w_1,a\rangle w_1+\langle w_1,b\rangle w_2$.

Thus, we find that $\langle w_1,a\rangle =1$ and $\langle w_1,b\rangle=0$.  Similarly, we find that $\langle w_2,a\rangle=0$ and $\langle w_2,b\rangle=1$.  In particular, $a$ is parallel to $w_1$ and $b$ is parallel to $w_2$.  Since $(w_1,w_2)$ forms an orthonormal basis of $W$, we see that $\langle a,b\rangle=\langle w_1,w_2\rangle=0$.  Thus, $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal.

Comment: How do you know $a$ and $b$ have magnitude 1?